# Add more images to the front page (index.php) banner and grab dynamically

Tags: php

okay, so very very new to PHP, and trying to complete my first major assignment.  I'm nearly finish however very stuck, and tutor/school have not been the most helpfull. I need to know how to solve this, in the easiest term so that i understand this for later. Thanks in advance.

question 2. 
so i have to Add more images to the front page (index.php) banner and make it rotate through the images. Store the images in the "Images/banner" folder and dynamically grab them.

how i have been able to create a javascript code to create the anner rotation, i just can't work out the php to dynamically grab them.

below is the banner page that allows upload of banner to image.banner folder.

i also have another question relating to same file which is

question 2
 There is a bug on the "editBanner.php" page. When you delete an image, that number is deleted. When a new file is uploaded, it is given the number of one more than the total of current banners. There is a major problem with this, e.g. if we have four banners: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. If we delete 2.jpg, we are left with 1.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. If we then uploaded a new image, the page would count the number of images (in this case three) and add 1, giving us a new file name of "4.jpg". We already have a file called 4.jpg, therefore, the old 4.jpg would be replaced. Find a way to fix this error so the images are never replaced

```
<?php
require_once("Includes/simplecms-config.php");
require_once("Includes/connectDB.php");
include("Includes/header.php");

confirm_is_admin();

$dir = 'Images/banner';
$confirmation = "";

if (isset($_GET["del"])) {
    if (file_exists($dir . "/" . $_GET["del"])) {
        unlink($dir . "/" . $_GET["del"]);
        $confirmation = $_GET["del"] . " deleted. <br><br>";
    } else {
        $confirmation = $_GET["del"] . " doesn't exist. <br><br>";
    }
}

$files = scandir($dir);
array_shift($files);
array_shift($files);

$newImage = COUNT($files) + 1;

if (isset($_GET["add"])) {
    $confirmation = "Image successfully uploaded.";
}

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    $allowedExts = array(
        "gif",
        "jpeg",
        "jpg",
        "png"
    );
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50 * 1024 * 1024) //50mb (1024 * 1kb = 1mb, 50 x 1024kb = 50mb)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
    ) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " 
           kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "
          <br>";
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dir .
                "/" . $newImage . "." . $extension);
            echo "Stored in: " . $dir . "/" . $_FILES["file"]
                ["name"];
            header("Location: editBanner.php?add=1");
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
?>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="admin">
            <?php
            if (!empty($confirmation)) {
                echo "<div id='confirmation'>" . $confirmation . "</div>";
            }

            for ($i = 0; $i < COUNT($files); $i++) {
                echo '<div id="bannerImage">';
                echo $files[$i] . ' - <a href="editBanner.php?del=' .
                    $files[$i] . '">Delete</a><br>';
                echo '<img src="' . $dir . '/' . $files[$i] . '"width="200px" height="100px" /><br>';
                echo '</div>';
                $files[$i--];
            }
            ?>

            <style>
                #bannerAdd {
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: 700px;
                }
            </style>
            <div id="bannerAdd">
                <form action="editBanner.php" method="post"
                      enctype="multipart/form-  data">
                    <h3>Upload a New Banner Image</h3>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of outer-wrapper which opens in header.php -->

<?php
include("Includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: this will give you better idea regarding the rotating banner (usually people call it slideshow) http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: as for the bug, maybe you want to change the naming rule to something that guarantee uniqueness eg: upload datetime (YYMMDDhh:mm:ss) http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. See with the slideshow i have the images in folder, and i have the javascript to create the show which is work, i just can't work out how to grab the the images dynamically once i have uploaded from the form.

Comment: could you show us the javascript code that you use do the slideshow? There are some possible ways to do this so if you show us your code we may be able to suggest the closest solution

Comment: var Banners = new Array('images/banner/1.jpg','images/banner/2.png', 'images/banner/3.png');
var CurrentBanner = 0;



  function DisplayBanners() {
    if (document.images) {
     CurrentBanner++;
     if (CurrentBanner == Banners.length) {
     CurrentBanner = 0;
     }
     document.RotateBanner.src=Banners[CurrentBanner];
     setTimeout("DisplayBanners()", 3000)
     }
    }

Comment: ive only added all images in to make sure the slide is working

Comment: I see. You can try to read the list of file in the `images` folder using php `scandir` http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php and print it in the HTML/JS. I'd suggest you print them as `<input type="hidden">` then read them using JS to make it cleaner. You can also print it directly to JS array to reduce the work

Comment: and please put all your codes in the question body instead of comment next time. It helps others to understand them easily

Comment: thanks very much for your help. much appreciated. thanks for the extra tip. very new to php and stack.

Comment: No prob. Good luck with your assignment